# Strategies for optimizing Redis SCAN performance or reducing Redis workload

Tags: go, optimization, redis

I have attempted to address the issue with Redis SCAN performance and high workload by implementing the following code snippet:

```
type go
it := common.RedisPool().Scan(ctx, 0, "match*", 1000).Iterator()
for it.Next(ctx) {
    // do something
}
```

However, I have noticed that each iteration of the loop takes approximately 2 minutes to complete, leading to slow performance. Additionally, the Redis workload is significantly high during this process.
Considering the large number of keys in my Redis instance (around 6 million), I was expecting a more efficient and faster execution of the SCAN operation, with reduced Redis workload.

How could I make the code I have shown above more efficient?